# Best way for JS architecture?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, frameworks

I'm looking to build a web app (online simple game) with javascript / HTML5 but I want a structured code.
I have do some research and Angular look like a good MVC framework.

http://angularjs.org/

Have you see other framework ? Angular is it a really good framework ?

Thanks

Edit: 
Maintain javascript code is not easy and quickly becomes unreadable without an architecture that helps to develop properly.
I have a simple little web project, players are by team and have some kind of action that infuence the actions of other players.
I want a framework that allows to manage all data easily.

A little way to flex and AS3, ca would be to create the component and integrate easily into the html code.

Backbone js seems to be effective for the data binding with epoxy.
or http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.databinding
I'll do more research because my question is too broad ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a very broad question that simply choosing a particular library won't solve. AngularJS is great, but I think it's important to understand how to scale a javascript application. Here is a video of a presentation given by Nicholas Zakas. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BGvy-S-Iag

Another good resource http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/

Knowing these concepts will allow you to build an application that is capable of dropping modules in and out seamlessly. You will be able to change a module without affecting any other module because your program will be loosely coupled. Additionally, should you choose to switch from Angular to something else, this framework will allow you to swap the base library easily and without breaking very much of your code.

Also, using modules and a mediator will make your code easier to test. Testing is important in any non-trivial application. I hope this helps!

If you're looking to just quickly create a web server that can serve your javascript application, I highly recommend Rails. You can get a server up and running in just 15 minutes. Another good MVC framework is NodeJs with Express. Almost as easy to use as Rails and it's purely Javascript whereas rails is Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of common MVC frameworks and you can choose one based on the complexity of you app and data models.
[List of common MVC frameworks](http://www.infoq.com/research/top-javascript-mvc-frameworks?utm_source=infoqEmail&utm_medium=WeeklyNL_ResearchContent&utm_campaign=031213news)

Comment: You can check this out too. Its an evaluation of the common frameworks available http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/

Comment: It's for build tiny online-games.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to build a structured App using Angular Js Use the directory structure of [ng-boilerplate](https://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate)